# PyMongo get analytics by field for given query

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

I have documents in mongo db, like

```
doc = {
    name = MyName,
    tags = tag1,tag2,tag3,
    ...
}
```

When I search documents by name, I also want to get analytics of tags, for docs with that name, like

```
{
   tag1: 7,
   tag2: 5,
   ...
   tagn: 14
}
```

How can I aggregate it?

Comment: Would you show your MongoDB document in JSON format?  Currently, I really don't know what you mean by `tags = tag1,tag2,tag3, ...`.  Would you also specify what you mean by "analytics"?  ... is it a count/sum of tag values?

Comment: tags is a string which contains many values joined by ','. By Analytics I mean to know how many docs have tags1, how many tags2 etc.
ex. 
doc1{
    name = AAAA,
    tags = tag1, tag2, tag3
}
doc2 {
   name = "AAAB",
   tags = tag2, tag3,tag5
}
doc3{
    name : AAAAAC,
    tags: tag3, tag1, tag7
}

I shoud get 
{
    tag1: 2,
    tag2: 2,
    tag3: 3,
    tag5: 1,
    tag7: 1
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data model complicates the query somewhat and the required output format complicates it even more ... but here's one way to do it.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "tags": {
        "$split": ["$tags", ","]
      }
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$tags"},
  {
    "$set": {
      "tags": {
        "$trim": {"input": "$tags"}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$tags",
      "count": {"$count": {}}
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {"_id": 1}
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": {
          "$arrayToObject": [
            [
              {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": {"$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"},
                  "initialValue": {},
                  "in": {
                    "$mergeObjects": [
                      "$$value",
                      {
                        "$switch": {
                          "branches": [
                            {
                              "case": {"$eq": ["$$this.k", "_id"]},
                              "then": {"k": "$$this.v"}
                            },
                            {
                              "case": {"$eq": ["$$this.k", "count"]},
                              "then": {"v": "$$this.v"}
                            }
                          ],
                          "default": "$$value"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$replaceWith": "$newRoot"}
])
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "tag1": 2,
    "tag2": 2,
    "tag3": 3,
    "tag5": 1,
    "tag7": 1
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Cq8Xqf83vm8).

Comment: @rickhghs thanks for the answer. And one more question pls. What should I add to this query, for having analytics just for documents which contain given tags? Like, get this analysis for documents, which have tag1 and tag3(only for doc1 and doc3 for this case). Search shoud be exact.

Comment: @gjivanya  You could add `{'$match': {'tags': {'$regex': '(?=.*tag1)(?=.*tag3)'}}}` as the first stage, like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hQmGWvB-Zqj "Link to mongoplayground.net -->").

Comment: @rickhghs and can I also get count of docs which match with given search in the same query?

Comment: @gjivanya I'm not sure what you mean.  Perhaps it would be better to ask a new question.